# How to generate running time graph for my Java program

Tags: java, graph

Hi I want to generate running time graphs on my java program. Is there any program which makes it?

Comment: Please rename your question to not use capital letters

Answer (score 2):

So, if the X-axis is time, what do want on the Y-axis?

If its memory, then you could use something [jconsole or jvisualvm](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#monitor)

Comment: Or if he just wants a 1-dimensional graph, then a wristwatch will suffice :)

Answer (score 1):

When you mean the time each method needs/total runtime then look for a profiler (e.g. eclipse plugin TPTP). Or do you mean to display  graphs of runtimes in your program itself? (The preposition "on" you use make it hard to understand for me, "in" or "for" would in my eyes clarify the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [jfreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) library.